# (Android Studio) Can't create MediaPlayer for files on SD card

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am scanning my SD card for audio files and store their file paths. That works fine. Later, I retrieve file path information to create URIs:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)));
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
I/System.out: URI: file:///storage/123A-45BC/Folder/Audio.mp3
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
    java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

That is basically the whole problem. What follows are just a few other things I tried, with either the same or different errors.

-) I tried creating MediaPlayer and indicate file paths like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.reset();

try {
     mp.setDataSource(filepath);
     // or: mp.setDataSource(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)));
     mp.prepare();
}
catch ...

// This results in the same error.
```

-) And I did try with Uri.parse:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(filepath));

// Uri.parse results in an "java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider" error,
// unlike Uri.fromFile.
// This tells me that I am on the right track with Uri.fromFile.
```

-) Is it a problem of missing user permissions? I do have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

file.exists() and file.canRead() both return true.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Dont use an Uri. Just try `mp.setDataSource(filePath);`.

Comment: I did try that too, forgot to add that, sorry!! That doesn't work either...

Comment: Okay... I can't get rid of this problem when trying with the emulator, but it disappears when porting the app to an actual device. I simply didn't expect different results there... Still glad to get some inputs as to why that is (because everything else I do with scanning SD cards - virtual and real - works well). But yeah, it's something I guess...

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I have this problem even in actual device.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the Uri with the FileProvider pattern:

````
FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.packageName + ".provider", file)```
````